# Add two numbers using linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

> #### 2. Add Two Numbers
>
> You are given two linked lists representing two non-negative numbers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.
>
> Input: `(2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)`
> Output: `7 -> 0 -> 8`

I've finished the code for the second problem in Leetcode. When I submitted my answer, I bumped into a runtime error when the input is two zeros. But when I used my own custom Testcase, it worked seemingly quite well.

I've checked my code really carefully, still can't find where the error is. Could you help me with that?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2) {
    struct ListNode* p1;
    struct ListNode* p2;
    struct ListNode* head;
    head = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode*));
    struct ListNode* cur = head;
    
    p1 = l1; p2 = l2;
    
    int sum, carry = 0, x, y;
    
    while(p1 || p2)
    {
        //Assign the values of the listnode to x and y.
        if(p1 != NULL) x = p1 -> val; else x = 0;
        if(p2 != NULL) y = p2 -> val; else y = 0;
        sum = x + y + carry;
        
        //Declare a new node nxt(next) and insert it after the current node
        struct ListNode* nxt;
        nxt = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode*));
        nxt -> val = sum % 10;
        carry = sum / 10;
        
        cur -> next = nxt;
        cur = cur -> next;
        
        if(p1 != NULL) p1 = p1 -> next;
        if(p2 != NULL) p2 = p2 -> next;
    }
    
    if(carry > 0)
    {
        struct ListNode* nxt;
        nxt = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode*));
        nxt -> val = carry;
        cur -> next = nxt;
    }
    
    head = head -> next;
    
    return head;
}
```

The error:

[image: The error]

Custom test case:

[image: custom testcase]

Comment: `(struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode*))` should be `malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode))`. You need to allocate enough space for a `ListNode`, not a pointer to one. And it's good style in C to omit casts for `malloc()`.

Comment: If you want to be sure that both node exists, replace `while(p1 || p2)` by `while(p1 && p2)` and after don't check if `(p1 != NULL)` or `(p2 != NULL)`.

Comment: Your list not NULL terminated. Also You have memory leak.

Comment: So how to edit the code then?

Answer (score 0):

> So how to edit the code then?

Exactly as John Kugelman wrote above:

```
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
…
        nxt = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    tmp = 0
    head = None
    tail = None
    
    
    while l1 or l2 or tmp != 0:
        if not l1 and not l2 and tmp != 0:
            n = ListNode(val=tmp)
            tail.next = n
            tail = n
            return head
        
        if not l1:
            val = l2.val + tmp
            tmp = val // 10
            val = val % 10
            n = ListNode(val=val)
            if not head:
                head = n
                tail = n
            else:
                tail.next = n
                tail = n
            l2 = l2.next
        
        elif not l2:
            val = l1.val + tmp
            tmp = val // 10
            val = val % 10
            n = ListNode(val=val)
            if not head:
                head = n
                tail = n
            else:
                tail.next = n
                tail = n
            l1 = l1.next
        
        else:
            val = l1.val + l2.val + tmp
            tmp = val // 10
            val = val % 10
            n = ListNode(val=val)
            
            if not head:
                head = n
                tail = n
            else:
                tail.next = n
                tail = n

            l1 = l1.next
            l2 = l2.next
        
    return head
```